# How to match a trigger on a specific field in mongodb stitch?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

The $match expression on mongodb's stitch application does not work properly.

I am trying to set up a simple update trigger that will only work on one field in a collection.

The trigger setup provides a $match aggregation which seems simple enough to set up.

For example if I want the trigger to only fire when the field "online" in a specified collection gets set to "true" I would do:

`{"updateDescription.updatedFields":{"online":"true"}}`

which for a stitch trigger is the same as:

`{$match:{{updateDescription.updatedFields:{online:"true"}}}`

The problem is when i try to match an update on a field that is an object.(for example `hours:{online:40,offline:120}`

For some reason $exists or $in does not work
So doing:

`{"updateDescription.updatedFields":{"hours":{"$exists":true}}`

does not work,neither does something like:

`{"updateDescription.updatedFields":{"hours.online":{"$exists":true}}`

The $match for the trigger is supposed to work exactly like a normal mongo $match.
They just provide one example :

```
{
  "updateDescription.updatedFields": {
    "status": "blocked"
  }
}
```

The example is from here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/database-triggers/

I tried 100's of variations but i can't seem to get it

The trigger is working fine if the match is a specific value like:

`{"updateDescription.updatedFields":{"hours.online":{"$numberInt\":"20"}}`

and then i set the hours.online to 20 in the database.

Comment: How do you check whether the trigger works or not ? Also, what is your update command ?

Comment: @Radu Tarcea what worked for you? And how would you update your solution to work with $or? If for instance you want to match when `hours.online` is either `20` or `10`, how would your solution to work with that? I have a similar problem and I'm using $or but the trigger doesn't match as I want it to. I've posted about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518308/my-or-selector-in-a-database-trigger-match-expression-doesnt-work-at-the-secon). Thanks!

Comment: Original question, but not exact same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518308/my-or-selector-in-a-database-trigger-match-expression-doesnt-work-at-the-secon

Answer (score 2):

I was able to have it match items by using an explicit `$expr` operator or declare it as a single field not an embedded object. ie. `"updateDescription.updatedFields.statue": "blocked"`

Comment: how would you update your solution to work with $or? If for instance you want to match when "statue" (or did you mean "status"?) is either "blocked" or "pending", how would you modify your match expression to work with that? I have a similar problem and I'm using $or (without $expr because $or apparently needs to always be the first operator) but the trigger doesn't match as I want it to. I've posted about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518308/my-or-selector-in-a-database-trigger-match-expression-doesnt-work-at-the-secon). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this myself, trying to get a trigger to fire when a certain nested field was updated to *any* value (rather than just one specific one).

The issue appears to have to do with how change streams report updated fields.

With credit and thanks to MongoDB support, I can finally offer this as a potential solution, at least for simpler cases:

```
{
    "$expr": {
        "$not": {
            "$cmp": [{
                "$let": {
                    "vars": { "updated": { "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields" } },
                    "in": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$updated.k", 0 ] }
                }},
                "example.subdocument.nested_field"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Of course replace `example.subdocument.nested_field` with your own dot-notation field path.