# My $or selector in a database trigger match expression doesn't work at the second level of nesting when configuring a database trigger

Tags: mongodb, database-trigger, mongodb-atlas

**Update**: I use "$match expression" to describe this but I don't actually use the $match operator. According to the docs, the selector should conform with $match's syntax, though the $match keyword is apparently not necessary in the actual expression.

**Update 2**: In the actual collection, `outerField` represents `message`, `fieldA` represents `fansNo`, and `fieldB` represents `sharedNo`. So `outerField.fieldA` represents `message.fansNo` and `outerField.fieldB` represents `message.sharedNo`. This is a stringified representation of the `updateDescription` field when the trigger fires (i.e. when I only specify `updateDescription.updatedField` in the match expression):

```
"updateDescription: {\"removedFields\":[],\"updatedFields\":{\"someOtherField\":310,\"message.fansNo\":1,\"updatedAt\":\"2020-06-22T13:29:08.829Z\"}}"
```

================================================================

**Original post**:

So I can't understand why it fails to trigger when I specify `message.fansNo` and `message.sharedNo` in the match expression.

I am setting up a [database trigger](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/database-triggers/) on updates to a collection, but I'm not able to get my [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) expression to work in filtering the change events that cause the trigger to fire. I want to fire the trigger only if one or both of 2 nested fields are present, say `fieldA` and `fieldB`. These 2 fields are nested inside an object, and the object is the value of a field in each document. Something like this:

```
// CollectionA schema
{
  _id: ...,
  outerField: {
    fieldA: 1 // or any number
    fieldB: 2 // or any number
  },
  ...
}
```

I have tried using this $match expression below, but the trigger doesn't fire:

```
{
  "$or": [
    {
      "updateDescription.updatedFields.outerField.fieldA": {"$exists":true}
    },
    {
      "updateDescription.updatedFields.outerField.fieldB":{"$exists":true}
    }
  ]
}
```

If I remove `outerField.<field>`, it works. That is:

```
{
  "$or": [
    {
      "updateDescription.updatedFields": {"$exists":true}
    },
    {
      "updateDescription.updatedFields":{"$exists":true}
    }
  ]
}
```

But of course that's not useful to me because the trigger will fire on any update at all.

I would provide a demo but I'm not sure how to create a sample that has database triggers configured.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the documents you are matching have the structure you expect?

Comment: @D.SM yes I'm sure.

Comment: @D.SM I've added more info, please have a look at the updates. Thanks!

Comment: Does `updateDescription.updatedFields.outerField` match? And why do you have `message.fansNo` with the dot in there?

Comment: @D.SM `outerField` represents `message`, `fieldA` represents `fansNo`, and `fieldB` represents `sharedNo`. So `outerField.fieldA` represents `message.fansNo`. Basically, `updateDescription.updatedFields.outerField` represents `updateDescription.updatedFields.message`, and no it doesn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to get around this problem by changing the query to watch for a field that gets updated at the same time but isn't nested. I think the problem with checking for a nested field is that the `ChangeEvent`'s `updateDescription` property doesn't contain the actual nested object that has changed; instead it contains the dot-notation representation of the change. So if you look at **Update 2** in my post you'll see that `updatedFields` has this value: `{\"someOtherField\":310,\"message.fansNo\":1...` instead of `{\"someOtherField\":310,\"message\":{\"fansNo\":1...`. By using `message.fansNo` in the $match query, Mongo will look for this object shape: `{\"message\":{\"fansNo\":1...`, which doesn't match in this case. A "real" solution here could be to escape the `.` in `message.fansNo` in my match expression, but I couldn't get that to work (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name)).

So the "solution" that worked for me is really just a workaround that works for my specific use-case: it so happens that `someOtherField` is always updated along with `message.fansNo`, and `someOtherField` isn't nested. So I can match `someOtherField` without worrying about nesting. Basically this match expression gives me the results I want:

```
{
  "$or": [
    {
      "updateDescription.updatedFields.someOtherField": {"$exists":true}
    },
    {
      "updateDescription.updatedFields.someOtherField":{"$exists":true}
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

```json
{
  "$expr": {
    "$ne": [{
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": { "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields" },
          "cond": { "$regexMatch": { "input": "$$this.k", "regex": "message\\.fansNo" } }
        }
      }
    }, 0]
  }
}
```

It's important to note that MongoDB interprets fields containing dots as nested objects. As a result, you cannot directly search for a field with dots using regular query syntax. To overcome this limitation and search for fields with dots, the provided query uses the `$objectToArray` operator to convert the `updatedFields` object into an array of key-value pairs. By doing so, the individual fields can be accessed and processed. The subsequent operations, such as `$filter` and `$regexMatch`, are then applied to the array elements, enabling the search for a field containing dots.

This approach allows the query to overcome MongoDB's default interpretation of dots as nested objects and effectively match the desired field, `message.fansNo`, even though it contains dots.